# Avagadro 1.2 ubuntu 16 installation error. CMAKE make

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make

I have been trying to install Avogadro 1.2 in ubuntu 16.4 I followed all the steps and installed all missing dependencies and finally end up with this error while compiling: cmake ../ and make command step according to the installation file instruction.

I have tried different versions of avogadro from their own site from github all endup same error. I have also removed eigen3 and installed eigen2 version but same problem.

But it works fine in ubuntu bionic bcoz it is default package.
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/avogadro/1.2.0-4build1

So if anyone guide me with installing from the above link or fix the below error then im happy.

```
surya@surya-Inspiron-N5010:~/avogadro-master/build$ make
[  0%] Generating moc_elementcolor.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target elementcolor
[  0%] Building CXX object libavogadro/src/colors/CMakeFiles/elementcolor.dir/elementcolor.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/openbabel-2.0/openbabel/atom.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/openbabel-2.0/openbabel/mol.h:42,
                 from /home/surya/avogadro-master/libavogadro/src/colors/elementcolor.cpp:31:
/usr/local/include/openbabel-2.0/openbabel/base.h:287:68: warning: unused parameter ‘replaceNewlines’ [-Wunused-parameter]
       virtual const char  *GetTitle(bool UNUSED(replaceNewlines) = true) const { return "";}
                                                                    ^
[  1%] Building CXX object libavogadro/src/colors/CMakeFiles/elementcolor.dir/moc_elementcolor.cxx.o
[  1%] Linking CXX static library elementcolor.a
[  1%] Built target elementcolor
[  1%] Generating ui_bsdysettingswidget.h
[  1%] Generating moc_bsdyengine.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target bsdyengine
[  1%] Building CXX object libavogadro/src/engines/CMakeFiles/bsdyengine.dir/bsdyengine.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/openbabel-2.0/openbabel/atom.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/openbabel-2.0/openbabel/mol.h:42,
                 from /home/surya/avogadro-master/libavogadro/src/engines/bsdyengine.cpp:39:
/usr/local/include/openbabel-2.0/openbabel/base.h:287:68: warning: unused parameter ‘replaceNewlines’ [-Wunused-parameter]
       virtual const char  *GetTitle(bool UNUSED(replaceNewlines) = true) const { return "";}
                                                                    ^
[  1%] Building CXX object libavogadro/src/engines/CMakeFiles/bsdyengine.dir/moc_bsdyengine.cxx.o
In file included from /home/surya/avogadro-master/build/libavogadro/include/avogadro/primitivelist.h:29:0,
                 from /home/surya/avogadro-master/build/libavogadro/include/avogadro/engine.h:37,
                 from /home/surya/avogadro-master/build/libavogadro/src/engines/../../../../libavogadro/src/engines/bsdyengine.h:29,
                 from /home/surya/avogadro-master/build/libavogadro/src/engines/moc_bsdyengine.cxx:9:
/home/surya/avogadro-master/build/libavogadro/include/avogadro/primitive.h:42:23: warning: ‘Avogadro::FALSE_ID’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   const unsigned long FALSE_ID = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max();
                       ^
[  1%] Linking CXX static library bsdyengine.a
[  1%] Built target bsdyengine
[  1%] Generating qrc_navigatetool.cxx
[  1%] Generating moc_navigatetool.cxx
[  1%] Generating ui_navigatesettingswidget.h
Scanning dependencies of target navigatetool
[  2%] Building CXX object libavogadro/src/tools/CMakeFiles/navigatetool.dir/navigatetool.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object libavogadro/src/tools/CMakeFiles/navigatetool.dir/eyecandy.cpp.o
In file included from /home/surya/avogadro-master/build/libavogadro/include/avogadro/painter.h:33:0,
                 from /home/surya/avogadro-master/libavogadro/src/tools/eyecandy.cpp:30:
/home/surya/avogadro-master/build/libavogadro/include/avogadro/primitive.h:42:23: warning: ‘Avogadro::FALSE_ID’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   const unsigned long FALSE_ID = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max();
                       ^
[  2%] Building CXX object libavogadro/src/tools/CMakeFiles/navigatetool.dir/moc_navigatetool.cxx.o
[  2%] Building CXX object libavogadro/src/tools/CMakeFiles/navigatetool.dir/qrc_navigatetool.cxx.o
[  2%] Linking CXX static library navigatetool.a
[  2%] Built target navigatetool
[  2%] Generating libavogadro_sv.qm
lconvert: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/lconvert': No such file or directory
libavogadro/src/CMakeFiles/avogadro.dir/build.make:486: recipe for target 'libavogadro/src/libavogadro_sv.qm' failed
make[2]: *** [libavogadro/src/libavogadro_sv.qm] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:148: recipe for target 'libavogadro/src/CMakeFiles/avogadro.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [libavogadro/src/CMakeFiles/avogadro.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: (Without looking at the code, so there may be other build issues at play here.) Turn off the `Wunused-variable` compiler warning, or fix the source so it doesn't use that variable.

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/lconvert` show?

Comment: @waltinator this command line shows it doesnot exist. but i already installed qt4 I ran qmake -version command it displays the following output   surya@Inspiron:~$ qmake -version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [see revisions of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1100723/5) to get confirmation that 1.2 version does not compile on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS because of problems with OpenBabel functions and related dependencies.

So we consider to use [`schroot`](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) mechanism. It will create small 18.04 LTS system inside your existing 16.04 LTS system. Both will use the same filesystem.

To setup `schroot` you need to execute the following commands (just copy and paste them):

```
sudo apt-get install schroot debootstrap -y

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/schroot/chroot.d/bionic.conf
[bionic]
description=Ubuntu 18.04
directory=/srv/chroot/bionic
root-users=$USER
type=directory
users=$USER
EOF

sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/bionic
sudo debootstrap bionic /srv/chroot/bionic

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /srv/chroot/bionic/etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
EOF

schroot -c bionic -u root apt-get update
schroot -c bionic -u root apt-get install avogadro
```

To run Avogardo 1.2 from terminal you need to run:

```
schroot -c bionic env DISPLAY=:0.0 avogadro
```

Optionally you can create `Avogadro.desktop` file for it and place it on Desktop:

```
cat <<EOF > ~/Desktop/Avogadro.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.2
Name=Avogadro
GenericName=Advanced molecular editor
Comment=Molecular Graphics and Modelling System
Exec=schroot -c bionic env DISPLAY=:0.0 avogadro
Icon=/srv/chroot/bionic/usr/share/pixmaps/avogadro-icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Qt;Science;Chemistry;Physics;Education;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=chemical/x-cif;chemical/x-cml;chemical/x-daylight-smiles;chemical/x-gamess-input;chemical/x-gamess-output;chemical/x-gaussian-log;chemical/x-mopac-out;chemical/x-pdb;chemical/x-xyz;chemical/x-gaussian-checkpoint;chemical/x-gaussian-cube;chemical/x-qchem-output;
EOF

chmod +x ~/Desktop/Avogadro.desktop
```

And enjoy the application:

[image: Avogadro 1.2 on 16.04 LTS]

Comment: The OP needs a specific version that is only packaged on later versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I will try this, the objective to install it is there is a quantum software ORCA that can only be analyzed using 1.2 version.

Comment: I dont want to upgrade to bionic bcoz it makes my laptop really slow and EPSON printer driver issue was there :(

Comment: Updated and tested answer with schroot method (you will have Avogadro 1.2 on 16.04 LTS).

Comment: Yes man it worked flawlessly :)  The graphics is poor anyway first impression its fine.

Comment: That's a nice trick I may use myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
walt@bat:~(1)$ apt-cache search lconvert
libv4l-0 - Collection of video4linux support libraries
libv4l-dev - Collection of video4linux support libraries (development files)
libv4lconvert0 - Video4linux frame format conversion library
qt4-dev-tools - Qt 4 development tools
addresses-goodies-for-gnustep - Personal Address Manager for GNUstep (Goodies)
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

Do you need to install some of these packages?

Comment: Yeah after installing the following dependency it worked but some options where not there and its extremely slow. I tried to compile with orig version it didnot work. It worked only with git cloned version. I think problem is while making cmake. It failed to create config.h link file in src folder. That problem is not there with git clone version

Comment: suod apt-get install libv4l-0
  266  sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
  267  sudo apt-get install libavogadro1
  268  sudo apt-get install libv4lconvert0
  sudo apt-get install dev-sip
  sudo apt-get install sip
  sudo apt-get install sip-dev
   sudo apt-get install doxygen
   sudo apt-get install docbook
   sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools
  sudo cmake