# Avogardo requires Qt4 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: qt5, qt4

I would be very happy about your help. I have the following problem, I absolutely need **avogardo 1.2** for my research. however, I did an ubuntu update without thinking the problems started.

1. ubuntu 20.04 installed
2. qt4 was updated to qt5
3. avogardo was automatically updated to **avogardo 2**.

I downloaded advogardo 1.2. and tried to install.
*-> following error _ Found unstable Qt version"5.12.8"
CMake Error at /usr ...../bin/qmake, this code requires Qt version 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakelists.txt:226 (fin_package)*

Then I found this on askubuntu and tried

*sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4*

*sudo apt-get update*

got still have the same problem as above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avagadro 1.2 ubuntu 16 installation error. CMAKE make](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100688/avagadro-1-2-ubuntu-16-installation-error-cmake-make)

Comment: Just to be sure: after 'sudo apt-get update' did you run 'sudo apt install qt4-x11' ?